# Silverlight XAP in Azure Cloud Storage

Tags: silverlight, azure, cross-domain, blob

I have a Silverlight xap that displays a green rectangle.

This xap is part of an ASP.NET website in the Azure cloud.

To make it easier to upgrade the Xap, I have moved it into Cloud Storage as a blob, and reference it with an https url.

Now the Xap does not start.  No error message is displayed.  There is white space where the xap should be.

I have searched the Internet for a solution.  There are many solutions for when the Xap is accessing a service on another domain, or accessing blob storage on another domain.  But this is not the same as my problem.  My xap does not access a service.  It displays a green rectangle.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you use some web traffic debugger (fiddler is quite good) to see what traffic you have between your browser and the remote application. That information might be crucial to solve your problem.

Comment: Have you added ClientAccessPolicy file in the $root blob container in your storage account? Also check if the blob container containing the XAP file is publicly accessible. You can check it out by directly accessing the XAP file through your browser - https://<youraccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<yourcontainer>/<yourxapfile.xap>.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Tom and Gaurav for getting me there.  Here is my solution:

1) Created a file called "clientaccesspolicy.xml". I used lower-case letters, not sure it matters.  In the file put the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
        <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
            <domain uri="*"/>
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
        </grant-to>
    </policy>
</cross-domain-access>
```

2) Uploaded this file to the root of your blob container.  Using VS2010 to access my blob storage, so cannot see the root ($root).  Wrote console app to upload and set the content-type.  Again, not sure if setting the content-type is necessary, but could be a gotcha.

This is the class I used:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class BlobStorageContainer
{

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Constants

    private const string BLOB_CONNECTION = <get this from the windows azure portal>;

    public const string ROOT_CONTAINER_NAME = "$root";


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Attributes

    private static CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;

    private static CloudBlobClient _blobClient;

    private CloudBlobContainer _container;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Construction

    static BlobStorageContainer()
    {

        // Create storage account
        _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(BLOB_CONNECTION);

        // Construct cloud blob client
        _blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    }

    public BlobStorageContainer(string strContainer)
    {

        // Get the audio-files container
        _container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(strContainer);

        try
        {

            // If container does not exist...
            if (!_container.Exists())
            {

                // Create container
                _container.CreateIfNotExists();

                // Set permissions
                BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob };
                _container.SetPermissions(permissions);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {

            // Reset reference
            _container = null;

            // throw back
            throw x;

        }
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Operations

    public void SetContentType(string strName, string strContentType)
    {

        // Retrieve the block-blob
        CloudBlockBlob blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(strName);
        if (blob.Exists())
        {

            // If props need changing...
            if (blob.Properties.ContentType != strContentType)
            {

                // Set properties
                blob.Properties.ContentType = strContentType;
                blob.SetProperties();

            }

        }

    }

    public void UploadFile(string strFilepath,string strName)
    {

        // Get blob
        CloudBlockBlob blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(strName);

        // Open file
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilepath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
        {
            blob.UploadFromStream(fs);
        } // using fs

    }

    public void WalkBlobs(Func<string, long, string, bool> fnCallback)
    {

        // Loop through the blobs
        foreach (IListBlobItem loop in _container.ListBlobs())
        {

            // If this is a block blob...
            if (loop is CloudBlockBlob)
            {

                // Get the blob
                CloudBlockBlob blob = loop as CloudBlockBlob;

                // Callback function
                bool bContinue = fnCallback(blob.Name, blob.Properties.Length, blob.Properties.ContentType);
                if (!bContinue)
                    break;

            }

        }

    }


}
```

}

and then did this in the Main function:

```
// Open container
BlobStorageContainer container = new BlobStorageContainer(BlobStorageContainer.ROOT_CONTAINER_NAME);

// Upload file
container.UploadFile(@"D:\Workspace\clientaccesspolicy.xml", "clientaccesspolicy.xml");

// Set content type
container.SetContentType("clientaccesspolicy.xml", "text/xml");
```

3) In my html, changed XAP urls from HTTPS to HTTP.  For some reason, this DID NOT WORK:

```
<param name="source" value="https://<blobaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/container1/MySilverlight.xap"/>
```

but this did:

```
<param name="source" value="http://<blobaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/container1/MySilverlight.xap"/>
```